# Multiplication operations on sets - Which makes the distributive law hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, products

Let $A,B,C$ be subsets of a ring $R$. Let's consider two arithmetic operations on sets.

We know that the sum of $A$ and $B$ is defined by $A+B=\left\{ a+b: a\in A,b\in B \right\}$.

For multiplication, there are **two** different kinds of **products**:

1. $\ AB=\left\{ ab: a\in A,b\in B \right\}$
2. $\ AB=\left\{ a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n: a_i\in A,b_i\in B,n\in N \right\}$

The question is, which of them obeys the distributive law below?

> $A(B+C)=AB+AC$
>
> $(A+B)C=AC+BC$

Any insights are much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried some examples?

Comment: @Karl Thanks for reminding. For the first type of multiplication, take A={1,2}, B={3}, C={4}. Then I find that just $A(B+C) \subseteq AB+AC$. The distributive law doesn't hold.

Comment: But the second multiplication is hard for me.